# Return async while having a thread still runnning (MVC .Net)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, jquery, asynchronous

I got the following problem, I want to execute a block of code that might take a while.

It would be a bad user experience if the user has to wait for it to finish. So I though of using a thread.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult methode(Model model){
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Do a block of code that takes a while
        });
    return Json(new
    {
        succes = GetValue()
    });         
}
```

When debugging you can clearly see that the thread is being executed and that the return code is reached.

Problem I got here is that the actual return takes place when the thread is done. ( so I am not gaining any speed here.)

Why is that? And how do I make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The way you have done it above won't work because as you have observed, you have await the task and then return, so effectively it's a synchronous operation from the user's point of view and they are stuck waiting for the server to respond with the actual results of the work.

There are a couple of ways to do this though, it depends on what the nature of the task is. If this is something that generates data that the user might want to come back to later on and download e.g a report that can take a while to generate:

1. Using an asynchronous controller, kick off the task and keep a record on the server side via some unique identifier, and then return immediately with that identifier.

   - A client-side script is then triggered to poll every N seconds via an `Ajax` call, to see if the work is complete on the server side
   - However if the app pool gets recycled in `IIS` during the running of this thread, the work is lost and you haven't really got a way to control this
2. Better yet kick off the long running task in a separate process and then the client can poll every few seconds(or use `SignalR` from the server side to push) for when the job is done.

   - A typical way to achieve this is to push a record of the work to be done into a `Queue` and then return some kind of identifier to the client.
   - Your separate process can just be running all the time and monitoring the queue for new work to do, it can then update a database or cache with the results of the work.
   - Meanwhile the client is polling (or `SignalR` is pushing whereby your signalr hub checks every few seconds and pushes the job status back to the client) to see if that particular "job" is completed.
   - This way you are not at the mercy of the web server process going down and trashing all your threads, plus you gain much better control over cases where you need to defer jobs, spread the load over multiple servers, etc.

If on the other hand this is data that just takes a while to calculate but is only going to be available to the user on-screen, and you don't allow the user to leave the current page whilst waiting for the results, then just use a properly asynchronous `Ajax` call from the client-side!

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. The task inside the task doesn't need to be returned to the client. It generates data that will be saved in a databse. So the best and easiest way would be a asynchronous controller?

Comment: @Jan - in that case I think that there is no need to have an async controller. Use approach #2 by queuing up the work and then return right away to the client. Execute the work in a completely separate process.

Comment: I am not sure how i should do this, could you maybe provide me with a code snipit or a example? Thanks in advance!